# Issues deleting git file after pushing

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-rm

I am trying to delete a file after git push. I initially tried to git rm myFile, but this resulted in deleting the file locally and not deleting the file from my repo. When I click on my branch, I see

> Conflict: Deleted on Source, Modified on Target

When I try to delete the cached file from the repo, my terminal does not see the file because it is deleted locally. The goal was to initially delete the file from my branch, and not locally. But the complete opposite happened.

Comment: Just delete the file from your computer system, make `git add .` and then `git commit -m "delete specific file" and `git push`it. So the file is permanently removed from the remote repo.

Comment: Also, I would say you should not do any changes on the cloud first, and then locally. You should ideally use separate branches all local and keep pushing those changes. Keeping the flow of code unidirectional can save you many sleepless nights.

Comment: Note that `git rm` does not delete a file from a *repository*. Repositories don't hold files in the first place: repositories hold *commits* (which then hold files). The `git rm` command removes a file from your working tree and from the *next commit you will make*, without affecting any of the existing commits. It's literally impossible to change any existing commit, so Git doesn't try.

Comment: Removing a file from your next however-many commits is normally just fine. Just remember that any time anyone uses one of the old historical commits, they get the file, and whenever anyone switches from a commit that has the file to one that lacks the file, that requires removing the file. Files aren't in "branches" or "repositories": instead, files are in (or not in) any one given commit. Note too that any given commit may be in one branch, or ten branches, or millions of branches (if you have that many).

Comment: In any case, what `git push` sends are *commits* (not files). Each commit holds a full snapshot of *every* file, so if you make new commits that omit the file in question, those new commits lack the file. Other commits have the file. Comparing two such commits gives you either "file added" or "file deleted" depending on which way you do the comparison. *Merging* means "do *two* comparisons and attempt to combine changes" and this is where you get into trouble.